# How can I use an htaccess rewrite rule to redirect away from an existing file?

Tags: php, apache

I have a directory called users which contains sub directories for each user. E.g. my directory structure might look like:

```
users/
    .htaccess
    UserAccess.php
    foo/
        baz.txt
    bar/
        passwd.txt
```

I want to prevent users from accessing other users files. Therefore, I wrote a php script which checks the path and prints the file contents or not. The problem is that the script is not being run, but rather apache is trying to access the files directly.

My .htaccess in the users/ directory is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^users/ UserAccess.php
```

A user would then try to access `http://mywebsite.com/users/username/file`. E.g. `http://mywebsite.com/users/foo/baz.txt`.

The key point is that `http://mywebsite.com/users/username/` is a REAL directory.

How do I fix this to accomplish what I want?

EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . UserAccess.php
```

doesnt work either.

Comment: well you could just rename the file UserAccess.php to index.php

Comment: how does that fix the problem? (didnt work when I tried it)

Comment: if you placed it in /users/ then it would run instead of a directory listing being produced (assuming your web server is set up that way, which it often is). Incidentally where do you have your UserAccess.php script?

Comment: Look at the directory structure above, also I added a bit to clarify at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that the subfolder (foo in the example) had permissions 700. This caused a 403 response before the rewrite rule was parsed. I changed the permissions to 701 and everything worked.

Comment: There's no way that anyone could have known that this was the problem.  :(

Comment: Im not blaming anyone, it was simply a problem that took me a long time to discover and therefore I posted the answer here so that some other fellow might not have to spend so long looking for the answer. (I +1'd all who helped)

Answer (score 2):

if your URL is like `http://example.com/users/...` adding:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

should make it work.

I've set an example on my computer with the following `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^testdir readHTACCESS.php
```

and it works just fine...

[LINK](http://shared.teneff.com/testdir/generic_button.png)

Comment: here is the difference: in my situation `http://mywebsite.com/users/foo/` is a valid directory, which Im guessing means that the htaccess file in users isnt being loaded

Answer (score 1):

To prevent direct access you can use `Deny from all` for all files except `UserAccess.php`.

Comment: Im currently using file/directory permissions to accomplish this, but the problem is that the UserAccess.php file isnt being run

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you need to use the mod_rewrite option
Take a look [here](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that mod_rewrite is alive and running on your server, and all we're dealing with is how to use it.  :-)

I suggest you specify an explicit path to UserAccess.php.  Do you know what the "working directory" is for your rewrite rule?

```
RewriteRule ^/users/ /users/UserAccess.php
```

I've tested this and it works for me.  If it doesn't for you, then perhaps there's a configuration problem that's not just the rewrite rule.  If that's the case, it would be very helpful to know what you're seeing in your access.log and error.log.

You can also perhaps simplify what's going on in PHP by feeding the filename as a variable:

```
RewriteRule ^/users/(.+\.txt) /users/UserAccess.php?what=$1
```

That way, you can skip parsing $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and just test for the existence of the file prior to sending it out with readfile() or equiv.

Comment: access_log: [09/Dec/2011:10:00:44 -0600] "GET /users/foo/baz.txt HTTP/1.1" 403 639 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2" error_log: empty

Comment: So I take it that specifying the path to UserAccess.php didn't help? Can you confirm that mod_rewrite is actually loading, and that your .htaccess file is being evaluated correctly?

Comment: Try accessing `/users/foo/baz.txt` where `/users/foo/` is a real directory

Comment: How can I check that the htaccess is being loaded and evaluated correctly?

Comment: mod_rewrite is working in a different htaccess file in a different folder ( a different rule, not this one)